# How to setup a configuration file for an ESP32 firmware?

Tags: esp32, firmware

#### Background story

I am working on a data logging application with an ESP32-based PCB retrieving data from multiple sensors and sending it to the cloud. Nothing too fancy here.

We have a lot of different sensors though, and most units only use a subset of the available sensors. We also have a lot of units to flash (hundreds). Hence I would like to implement the firmware in such a way that

1. The firmware is super generic and able to interact with all the sensors if it needs to.
2. A configuration file (YAML, JSON, CSV, whatever) can be flashed alongside the firmware and this config file would specify

   - The ID of the unit being flashed
   - The list of the sensors to enable
   - The Wifi credentials to use

That way there would have no need to recompile the firmware every time we need to flash a new unit and anyone (even non-technical people) would be able to conveniently flash the ESP32 with a tool like https://esp.huhn.me/ and a text editor to edit the config file.

#### Question

I already have the generic firmware and I already know how to read and parse a file in C/C++. What I don't know is how to use https://esp.huhn.me/ to flash both the firmware and the configuration file. I also don't know how I can tell the firmware to fetch the config file at the right location in the file system, this remains kind of obscure to me.

Comment: As a general starting point, take a look at the documentation and the examples. There are examples for storing configuration data (NVS), example for storing more generalized data (flash), examples for reading/writing data in files and an API for a FAT-like file-system structure. There are examples for each and every single digital interface of the system, so you can either preload your configuration at factory-programming or do it later by bluetooth or wifi or serial etc.